# @value of other static value of a class (in other package) with javadoc

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I have a class which holds many static values (int and Strings). In other classes I want to add this values of the static attributes. For instance, I have this servlet: `LoginServlet` and this comment in it:

```
* Possible errors: <br>
 * 1. Bad request (not valid parameters) - {@value com.minyanserver.utilities#ServerConsts.BAD_REQUEST}. <br>
 * 2. General error - {@value #ServerConsts.GENERAL_ERR}. <br>
```

both options don't work, instead of value I am getting nothing: `* 1. Bad request (not valid parameters) -`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching in the documentation I noticed I have an error. Here how it should be done:

```
{@value com.minyanserver.utilities.ServerConsts#BAD_REQUEST}
```

and not like this:

```
{@value com.minyanserver.utilities#ServerConsts.BAD_REQUEST}
```